# I forgot the Glassfish3 master-password, how can i reset it?

Tags: glassfish, glassfish-3

I forgot the master-password of my Glassfish 3.1.2.2. Is there a way to reset it? I spent a lot of time "googling around" but i didn't find a suitable answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Please follow the below steps:

1. Stop the domain
2. Back up the master password file
3. Create a new domain and save the master password:
   **asadmin create-domain --savemasterpassword domain2**
4. Remember the password :-)
5. Copy the newly created masterpassword file over the old one
6. Delete the newly created domain:
   **asadmin delete-domain domain2**

FYI, now you should also know why you want to protect the master password file using file permissions :-)

Comment: As i remember, the keystore is protected with the master-password. So, i have to overwrite the old one with the keystore of domain2 too?

Answer (score 17):

There is a backup password that can be used to access the administrator panel even if you've forgotten the main one.

If you navigate to `glassfish\domains\domain1\config\` you will find a file called `local-password`.

The contents of that file can be used as a password to log in to the control panel as admin.

Answer (score 0):

This was a big problem for me after inheriting a testing VM from a colleague who left the company.  I didn't want to risk creating a new domain as described above and I tried using the contents of *local-password* file as also described above, but that didn't work for me.

What did work first time was the following on GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.2.2 (build 5). Change contents of this file:

```
$GLASSFISH_HOME$\glassfish\domains\domain1\config\admin-keyfile
```

with:

```
admin;{SSHA}WQVj8i9CLECCiv+w6ZxGgMrcfPqHPoXZW+2Jdw==;asadmin
```

I didn't add a newline or carriage return at the end of the line.

This is my modification of an [online solution](http://smoumie.blogspot.it/2014/01/reset-glassfish-password-solved.html).

Answer (score 0):

Copy the admin-keyfile from origin install zip (empty password).

Comment: This should be comment

Answer (score 0):

For Glassfish 4,  after creating domain2 with default passwords, I also had to copy keystore.jks and domain-passwords files along with the master-password before change-master-password would recognise the password.